# Laravel relationship through a parent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a model for services that are packed with modules and each modules has a price. Multiple modules create the price for that service.

```
- Service #1
-- Module 1 ($20)
-- Module 2 ($40)
```

Using `belongsToMany`

```
class Services extends Model
{
    public function modules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Services\Modules');
        ...
```

each module links to a price

```
class Modules extends Model
{
    public function price()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Services\Pricing', 'product')->where('type', 'module');
        ...
```

and a `service_module` table that links services to modules. The problem is what kind of relationship should I create to be able to `->sum()` the **module** prices for each **service** because I created an ugly patch with loops and burning 15 more queries per request

```
$prices = [];
foreach ($services->modules as $modules )
    $prices[] = $modules ->price['month'];
$price = number_format(collect($prices)->sum(), 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to load your relationships along with the `services` query to turn those 15 extra queries into one extra query.

Code examples in the linked docs should be enough to get you started.